# Create a report with filter from different layer using Atlas

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, filter, expression, atlas

I have the following scenario:

- Layer ‘grid’, with a field called ‘number’
- Layer ‘log’ with field called ‘number’ in common with ‘grid’ layer and another field called ‘date’
- Layer ‘problem’ with field called ‘number’ in common with    ‘log’ and ‘grid’ number and another field called ‘type’

Now I’d like to make layout with Atlas enabled; in every page I need to print some fields from layer ‘log’ filtered by the common field ‘number’ from ‘grid’ layer.

On the same page I need also some field from layer ‘problem’ filtered by the common field ‘number’ from layer ‘grid’.

Unfortunately I cannot use $atlasfeatureid as filter since  I deleted some grid on the ‘grid’ layer and there’s no more correspondence.

Comment: no idea on how to do?

Comment: The explication it's not very clear... Add details and clarification about the different set up between the layers : points, lines ort polygons? Precise the QGIS version. What do output do you want?  etc....